# monitor payload sizes to sagemaker endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have an app that is used by customers, and I need a way to monitor the size of the data they are sending to my sagemaker endpoints so I can bill them appropriately. I looked at the cloud watch API, but there doesn't seem to be anything that can achieve this. Does anyone have an idea for how something like this can be achieved via AWS?

Comment: Are you using any sort of proxy ? Proxy logs might help you for this need.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 options:

1. As part of "pre-processing" in the container running on the endpoint, you could capture the request in the inference script, calculate the size of the payload and write the information to say DynamoDB.
2. If you own the client making the call to the endpoint then just calculate the size before sending it to the SageMaker endpoint and say write the information to say DyanoDB.
3. Enable data [capture on the SageMaker endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-monitor-data-capture-endpoint.html) to capture all the request. You can then see the exact payloads your customers sent to the endpoint and calculate the size yourself.